# Reading a text file in R

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table

I've always read in text files in R ok without any problems. I have just noticed today that when reading a text file in RStudio, it automatically imports the variables as factors. This is easily fixed with `stringsasFactors = F` but then it now imports every column as a character. I'm using read.table for this as in:

```
read.table("file.text", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)
```

Anybody know how to get the `read.table` command to import text file columns as numeric? I've searched around a bit but it would be useful to know if anybody else is having the same issues with `read.table`.

Comment: specifying `stringsAsFactors = F` does not import _every_ column as a character, but only those columns where a non-numeric character is found anywhere in the column.  If you are expecting a column to appear as numeric and it is appearing as character, then there is something non-numeric in that column.

Comment: Thanks for that useful hint.

Comment: As you've rightly pointed out, it turns out the problem is that I have a non-numeric character in .text file which I've managed to fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a vector which contains the classes of the columns which you intend to read.  For example, if your source data had two columns, the first which you wanted as numeric, and the second as factor, then you coul use this:

```
classes <- c(col1="numeric", col2="factor")
read.table("file.text", colClasses=classes, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. What if I wanted all columns to be numeric? There are more than 10 columns.

Comment: @John Then just use `numeric` everywhere.

Comment: As in `classes = c("numeric")` and `read.table`? Do I need to specify every column or is there another of doing it?

Comment: Use `rep("numeric", times)`, where `times` is the number of columns you have in your input file.